# Запуск Java-Servlet внутри PHP-проекта, реально ли?

Tags: php, java, servlet, tomcat, apache2

Суть задачи такова:
Есть сайт (локальный), написан на PHP. Нажимается кнопка "сканировать файлы", и далее уже java-код производит сканирование файлов PDF (из сетевой папки), производит необходимую сортировку, занесение информации в БД (имя файла, путь к файлу, кол-во страниц, и т.д.), и как результат - php-страничка динамически обновляется (через AJAX) и показывает уже результат (который был занесен в БД).
Далее, нажимаю "Печать" этого файла, и далее java-код внутри сервера отправляет уже файл на локальный принтер (естественно без открытия этого файла пользователем, код на java уже есть), присутствующий в системе (имена заранее известны), с отдачей статистики (отправлено/ошибка).
В качестве серверной ОС используется CentOS.
Была мысль использовать `proc_open()` либо `exec()`, но иногда нужно, чтобы при роуте `host/about` - выводилась php страница, а в `host/settings` - результат java-кода.

1. Возможно ли сделать разные роуты сайта с разным кодом, и как я полагаю, нужно использовать `связку Tomcat + Apache2` (и как именно это все будет работать)? Или есть более простые вещи?
2. Как проще и лучше запустить java-код, после команды "сканирование" и "печать"?

Comment: Можно из java кода отправлять json /xml и отображать его через php. Тоесть запустить java уод из php и ждать от него json/xml данные их отпарсить и отрисовать на странице

Comment: @AlexZaslavskis, а как будет корректней запустить, просто jar-файл через exec(), либо настроить Tomcat и делать команды уже через curl/другие методы?

Comment: @AlexZaslavskis а еще java-код отдает информацию постепенно, не разом.

Comment: Пусть отдает как java коду удобно ,после ты просто принимаешь его в php

Comment: запустите через tomcat и сделайте ответы (куча библиотек есть для этих целей)

Answer (score 0):

Можно через exec(), но это если java запускается редко (несколько раз в минуту) -- ей нужно порядочно ресурсов, чтоб запуститься и разогнаться.

Можно настроить проксирование через Apache2 -- `ProxyPass ...`.

Можно поднять nginx или haproxy перед обоими:

`/usr/sbin/haproxy -f my_haproxy.cfg`

```
defaults
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client  900s
  timeout server  900s
frontend fe_http
  mode http
  bind :1080 
  acl a_api path_beg /api/
  use_backend be_api if a_api
  default_backend be_http
backend be_http
  mode http
  server se_http 127.0.0.1:3000
backend be_api
  mode http
  server se_http 127.0.0.1:9000
```